# Apex Trigger to update the value of Related to company field ( if it is null only) on the task object based on the related to contact

Tags: salesforce

I need to write a trigger to pre-fill the value of "Related to: company" field ( if it is null only) on the task object based on the "related to: contact" field value before submitting the record. Please help me how can I achieve this.

Thanks, Shweta

Answer (score 0):

trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after update) {
    for(Task newTask : Trigger.New){
        // Task.WhoId != null                      **----Checks Contact is null or not**
        // ((string)Task.WhoId).startsWith('003')  **----Checks Task is related to Contact**
        // Task.WhatId == null                     **----Checks the related to field is null or not**
        if(Task.WhoId != null && ((string)Task.WhoId).startsWith('003') && Task.WhatId == null ){
            **// Add your code as per your needs.**
        }
    }
}